# using SQL COUNT function or executing search query directly which is more efficient

Tags: sql

Let's say i have a very big database , if i execute a search query directly then count the returned rows would it be more faster ? Or using COUNT(searchquery) then start executing query like ->

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE bla='blabla'
OFFSET 0 FETCH  NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

I searched for it but i couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the count in the database!  It will be much faster.

First, a `count(*)` only returns one row and one value.  That is much, much less data -- and much faster -- than returning all the rows.

Second, a `count(*)` does not reference any columns in the `select`, so the query can be better optimized.  It might be possible to get the count without ever looking at the data pages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing paging. You need the total count to do display the total count and calculate the total number of pages to the user, yes?

Than Gordon's answer is the one to use.

Comment: Yes @Gordon Linoff gave the answer i was looking for i am going to mark it as answer as soon as i can :)  , i wasnt sure if COUNT would be more efficient